# Memory Leaks in my Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My application calls bunch of API's which returns lots of data which are manipulated inside my controller to give various insights (passed onto my view).

The problem is that I have been having memory leaks in my application for which I currently need to restart my application after few number of requests.

Also, I have been caching all of my api calls to improve the performance of my application. Most of my data is stored in form of hashes when returned by the api and this data is manipulated (sort of duplicated using groupby).

I'm using Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3.2. I need to know how can I remove this memory leak from my application.

Comment: Are you sure you have a memory leak or is it possible that your caches eat up memory (because that is what caches do)? Also you might want to post your code - without code all we can do is guessing...

Comment: I have seen the cache folder size and it doesn't seem to be too big, around 20MB. I would have posted the code but it is too complicated having dependencies on other modules. I'm looking for common pitfalls that we programmers do in RoR that causes memory leaks.

Comment: As a side note: Both - [Ruby 1.9](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/01/10/ruby-1-9-3-will-end-on-2015/) and [Rails 3.2](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2015/1/6/Rails-4-1-9-and-4-0-13-have-been-released/) - are outdated. There won't be any bug fixes nor security updates for this versions. You might consider upgrading to newer versions.

Answer (score 12):

You should confirm, that you indeed have a memory leak and not a memory bloat. 
You can read about ruby GC [here](https://samsaffron.com/archive/2013/11/22/demystifying-the-ruby-gc)

`GC.stat[:heap_live_slot]` - this one represents the objects which are not cleared after last GC. If this number steadily increases request by request, then you can be sure, that you have a memory leak.

Comment: This is a good way to start. I'm pretty sure I have a memory leak and not a bloat because after certain number of request my application crashes. Does having too much processing in controllers affect it, should I be moving more of my logic into modules?

Comment: The number which it gives is it in bytes?

Comment: No, it's just a count of references to objects.

Answer (score 9):

First you can check a list of Ruby gems that have memory leaks first.

Refer (https://github.com/ASoftCo/leaky-gems)

Comment: Nopes.. I don't use any of these gems, but indeed a helpful list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **bundler-leak** gem to find memory leaks in your gem dependencies.

https://github.com/rubymem/bundler-leak